# LangChain and Gradio : Fail to add ConversationBufferWindowMemory

Tags: py-langchain, gradio

I fail to add memory to my chatBot...
please help !

I m stuck here , with always the same error :

```
 in _validate_inputs
    raise ValueError(f"Missing some input keys: {missing_keys}")    
ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'history'}
```

here is my code and i don't understand how to populate 'history'

Whatever i do, i fail to inject or create 'history' to be added to the prompt
the code work fine without any memory related line

```
def get_prompt():
  
  return """
  ###Previous conversation:
  {history}
  ### Instruction:
Context: {context}
User Question: {question}
###
Response:
"""

def process_llm_response(llm_response):
    if not llm_response:
      return "Please enter a question"

    query = llm_response['query']
    response = llm_response['result']
    response = response.split("### Response")[0]
    #history=maMemory.load_memory_variables({})
    
    #maMemory.save_context({"input": query},{"output": response})
    #maMemory.save_context(input= "hi",output= "whats up")

    return response

def startChat():

   embedding_directory = "/chromaBlagues"
   embedding_model=SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(sentence_transformer_ef)
   embedding_db = Chroma(collection_name="myBlagues",
                         persist_directory=embedding_directory,
                         embedding_function=embedding_model)

   

   prompt_template = get_prompt()

   llama_prompt = PromptTemplate(
       template=prompt_template, input_variables=["history","context","question"]
   )
   
   chain_type_kwargs = {"prompt": llama_prompt}

   retriever = embedding_db.as_retriever( search_kwargs={'k': 2})

   #Init mémoire
   maMemory = ConversationBufferWindowMemory()

   qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm,
                                       chain_type="stuff",
                                       retriever=retriever,
                                       memory=maMemory,
                                       chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs,
                                       return_source_documents=False)

   def runChain(query,history):
     return process_llm_response(qa_chain(query))

   app = gradio.ChatInterface(runChain)
   app.queue()
   app.launch(share=False, debug=True)


startChat()
```